# Blocking FTP with iptables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

Hi all into my ubuntu server I want to block the ftp port for all except my ip:
123.123.123.123

How is possible this?

Comment: Yes but I wanna be sure what I set into iptables because I have a lot of site into this server

Answer (score 4):

Write a rule which blocks all the incoming traffic for FTP, assuming the FTP port is 21:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 21 -j DROP
```

Then write the following rule to exclude your IP from being blocked:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s 123.123.123.123 -p tcp --destination-port 21 -j ACCEPT
```

The -I parameter will insert the rule at the top of the stack. Since we didn't provide any rule number, it will be inserted at the top by default.

Comment: If I write the first iptables return me No chain/target/match by that name why? what is wrong?